# functional field odoo type float , new api

Tags: python, api, odoo, field, odoo-8

I'm trying to make an operation * on a field , i have tried functional fields but it didn't work , now i'm trying this @api.depends api , does it work with odoo 8 ? it still not work

```
class fleuret(osv.Model):           
    _inherit = "mrp.bom.line"
    _columns = {
                'unit_price' : fields.float(string='unit price', related='product_id.lst_price', store=True, readonly=True),
                'amount' : fields.Float(string='price ',store=True, readonly=True,digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),compute='_compute_price'),
                }
    @api.one       
    @api.depends('product_qty')
    def _compute_price(self):
        self.amount =(unit_price * self.product_qty)
```

Comment: In old api `Float` should be lower case and you are mixing between new and old api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp

class fleuret(models.Model)
    _inherit = "mrp.bom.line"


    unit_price = fields.Float(
        string='unit price', related='product_id.lst_price',
        store=True, readonly=True)
    amount = fields.Float(
        string='price', store=True, digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),
        compute='_compute_price')

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('product_qty', 'unit_price')
    def _compute_price(self):
        for r in self:
            r.amount = r.unit_price * r.product_qty
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from openerp import models,fields,api
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp

class fleuret(models.Model)
    _inherit = "mrp.bom.line"

    @api.one       
    @api.depends('product_qty')
    def _compute_price(self):
        self.amount =(self.unit_price * self.product_qty)

    unit_price = fields.Float(string='unit price', related='product_id.lst_price', store=True, readonly=True)
    amount = fields.Float(string='price',store=True,digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),compute='_compute_price')
```

Comment: it becomes problem with xml now , unit_price and amount are not known !

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, that code snippet is correct and fully compatible with new api. (@Hardik Patadia: api.one is deprecated since Odoo V9)

Answer (score 1):

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
from openerp import models,api, _
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
class fleuret(osv.Model):           
    _inherit = "mrp.bom.line"
    _columns = {
                'unit_price' : fields.float(string='unit price', related='product_id.lst_price', store=True, readonly=True),
                'units_price' : fields.float(string='price ',store=True, readonly=True,digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),compute='_compute_price'),
                }
    @api.one       
    @api.depends('product_qty')
    def _compute_price(self):
        self.units_price = (self.unit_price * self.product_qty)
```

Comment: Please add a description to your solution?